# How to get value from list in java which is added from hash map

Tags: java, list, collections

I have some doubt regarding the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String,String> hMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    System.out.println("Size of HashMap : " + hMap.size());
    hMap.put("1", "One");
    hMap.put("2", "Two");
    hMap.put("3", "Three");
    System.out.println("Size of HashMap after addition : " + hMap.size());
    // remove one element from HashMap
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
    list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    list.add(hMap);
    System.out.println(""+hMap.get(1));
    System.out.println(""+list.size());
    //if(list.size()<1)
    System.out.println(""+list.get(0));
}
```

**Output**

```
Size of HashMap : 0
Size of HashMap after addition : 3
null
1
{3=Three, 2=Two, 1=One}
```

**Myquestion**

How do I get each value from the list?

Comment: What do you mean by get each value from the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list has a single object which is a Map. If you wish to get the values of that single Map, just iterate over them :

```
for (String value : list.get(0).values()) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

If your list has multiple entries, you can use nested loops :

```
for (Map<String,String> map : list)
    for (String value : map.values()) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
```

Comment: now am having more than one object in that list how to get that?

Comment: @Test-Developer That's what I shown in my code. Iterate over full list. Read all answers at least before asking further questions. Show some respect to your answers.

Comment: @Test-Developer You iterate over the list as well

Answer (score 1):

> how to get the each value from list?

Just iterate over list and get each value

```
for (HashMap<String, String> currentmap : list) { // foreach loop   
      System.out.println(currentmap);// do something with currentmap
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : currentmap.entrySet()) {
      System.out.println(entry.getValue()); //each value of map
   }
}
```